# Unable to redirect `coproc` streams using FD 5 and 6, but not 3 and 4. Why?

Tags: linux, macos, command-line, bash

On OSX, while attempting to expose a service implemented as a bash script, and started with `coproc`, to a client implemented as a bash script, by passing the IO streams of the service to the client, I discovered I could use variables 5 and 6, but not 3 and 4 to hold the streams. I expected to be able to use any number 3 or above.

For example, the following works:

If service `./capitalize` is

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while true; do 
    read line
    echo "${line^}"
done
```

and `./client` is

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
lsof -p $$ | grep PIPE
echo $1 >&6
read line <&5
echo Result: "${line}"
```

and we check our bash version, start the service, and reflect on the exposed pipes

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.0.18(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin19.5.0)
$ coproc SVC { ./capitalize; }
$ echo ${SVC[@]}
63 60
$ lsof -p $$ | grep PIPE
bash    30833 Setup   60   PIPE 0xaafc4e53240e4cbe    16384                     ->0x1eca6ceb32d18709
bash    30833 Setup   63   PIPE 0x904d6242c4e8c148    16384                     ->0xe8caffae10f9dd84
```

and then execute

```
$ ./client "foo" 5< /dev/fd/${SVC[0]} 6> /dev/fd/${SVC[1]}
bash    31441 Setup    5   PIPE 0x904d6242c4e8c148    16384                     ->0xe8caffae10f9dd84
bash    31441 Setup    6   PIPE 0xaafc4e53240e4cbe    16384                     ->0x1eca6ceb32d18709
Result: Foo
```

then things behave as expected. `foo` has been capitalized to `Foo` and we can see the `capitalize` output and input streams have been re-maped into `client` as `63 -> 5` and `60 -> 6`.

However, if I change the file descriptors from 5 -> 3 and 6 -> 4, then things unexpectedly fail. They fail because descriptors 3 and 4 do not get passed to `client`.

If `./client` is updated to

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
lsof -p $$ | grep PIPE
echo $1 >&4
read line <&3
echo Result: "${line}"
```

then executing

```
$ ./client "foo" 3< /dev/fd/${SVC[0]} 4> /dev/fd/${SVC[1]}
./client: line 3: 3: Bad file descriptor
./client: line 4: 4: Bad file descriptor
Result:
```

yields no results because the file descriptors do not appear!

So why can I use `5/6`, but not `3/4`? Are `3/4` reserved? How would I know that?

---

Also, if I executing using an alternate syntax for redirection then the streams are not redirected even though I thought the syntax where semantically equivalent.

So changing this

```
$ ./client "foo" 5< /dev/fd/${SVC[0]} 6> /dev/fd/${SVC[1]}
```

to

```
$ ./client "foo" 5<&${SVC[0]} 6>&${SVC[1]}
```

results in

```
./client: line 3: 6: Bad file descriptor
./client: line 4: 5: Bad file descriptor
Result:
```

Aren't those two syntaxes for redirection, `5< /dev/fd/${SVC[0]}` and `5<&${SVC[0]}` supposed to be equivalent?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Observation: In Bash 5.0.3 in Debian 10 the main problem does not occur (in Linux I need to `grep` for `FIFO`, hardly relevant; anyway there is no `Bad file descriptor` for `3` nor `4`, these descriptors work as well as `5` and `6`). The other issue is a separate issue.

Comment: Thanks! At least I know I'm not going outta my mind!